# How to keep Tableview scrolling and how to delete empty space between prototypecell and tableview in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I have two questions regarding tableview in Swift3

Here my tableview is not scrolling and even i uncheck the adjust scroll view insets in UiView attribute inspector then also empty space above the cell is not deleting.

Here why my tableview is not scrolling even the scroll is enabled 
How to scroll tableview is there any thing to do in my code

Please help me in the two questions

I have written code like below

```
import UIKit

class movieViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableviewLayout: UITableView!

    var itemsArray = ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableviewLayout.isScrollEnabled = true
        scrollToLastRow()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tableviewLayout.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-35, 0, 0, 0);
      //only this is working   
      //but when i uncheck the adjust scroll view insets why it is not working
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {  
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = itemsArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func scrollToLastRow() {
        let indexPathrow = NSIndexPath(row: itemsArray.count - 1, section: 0)
        self.tableviewLayout.scrollToRow(at: indexPathrow as IndexPath , at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you set tableviewLayout.dataSource and tableviewLayout.delegate to self?

Comment: I do not see anything weird in the code, it should be working. How about your storyboard or XIB file or constraints, can you post it? The spaces problem should be dealt with constraints.

Comment: In order to scroll, you should call the scrollToLastRow in viewDidAppear

Comment: @Vamshi Krishna i did not written self.delegate in viewdidload() directly i have given in storyboard and i have set all the delegates to tableview

Comment: @Shhalva Avanashvili i did not use xib file i make tableview as a grouped and i have added prototype cell and for trail i have taken one label and given constraints like leading space, top space, width and height but for the first cell i got empty space 35 even i have uncheck the viewcontroller  adjuct scrollview insect

Comment: @Farid Al Haddad  Thank you when i call scrollToLastRow() method in viewDidAppear it is working but it is directly going to end from there it is not moving means when i try to scroll it is not scrolling did i miss anything else

Comment: @ Vamshi Krishna Thhank you

Comment: Shalva Avanashvili Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`scrollToLastRow()` will not work in the `viewDidLoad` method. You should use it in the `viewDidAppear` method and it will work fine.

Comment: Thank You Nishant Bhindi when i call scrollToLastRow() method in viewDidAppear it is working but it is directly going to end from there it is not moving means when i try to scroll it is not scrolling did i miss anything else

Comment: You mean the scroll animation is not happening? It should be since you have given the `animated` property to `true`. Still if it is not happening then use perform ` self.perform(#selector(self.scrollToLastRow), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.2)`

Please provide up vote or correct the answer if it really helps you.